# Can I get WCHAN from ps on Mac OS X 10.7.4?

Tags: kernel, process, osx, ps

From the manual it seems that `ps -AO wchan` should tell me what everything is sleeping on, but everything comes up as `-`. (And `nwchan` as `0`). Did they do away with the old `sleep()`/`tsleep()` interface in the kernel, or do I need to tweak some setting to get at the information?

And if `p->p_wchan` is actually always zero in Darwin 11, is there another way find out what processes are waiting for?

EDIT: Indeed, `p->p_wchan` isn't even defined in the internal `struct proc`, the `sysctl` interface just zeroes out the fields when exporting. There's `uu_wchan` and `uu_wmesg` members in `struct uthread`, set by the `_sleep` interface and through that by the emulated `tsleep` function, but I haven't found anything to make those available to userland. `ps -MAO wchan` doesn't, for one.

(The whole `struct uthread` thing seems to be a very specific to XNU, a way of retrofitting FreeBSD interfaces onto Mach, so there's little hope of finding solutions from elsewhere).